# What makes PBE the most preferred functional over other GGA functionals?

Tags: density-functional-theory

There are many GGA functionals like PW91, PBE, and BLYP. However the most popular functional is the PBE.

What is the reason PBE functional so popular?

Comment: Popular for what application? Is it possible to elaborate on your application?

Comment: It's always a good idea to write abbreviations out explicitly the first time you use them.

Comment: I will rephrase the question with details

Comment: Some (absolutely not representative data) on popular (as in the populus votes) functionals: http://www.marcelswart.eu/dft-poll/

Answer (score 14):

Here is an introduction to DFT functionals: https://dft.uci.edu/pubs/RCFB08.pdf

In short, the Perdew-Burke-Ernzerhof (PBE) functional is very popular because it is a non-empirical functional with reasonable accuracy over a wide range of systems. While PBE is typically not the most accurate GGA (generalized gradient approximation) functional for a given system, it usually is not too far off either. Empirical functionals offer better accuracy for systems they are parametrized for, e.g. "BLYP has smaller errors for main-group organic molecule energetics", but fail in others.